# Binding hyperlink in gridview using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, hyperlink

How to *Bind* hyperlink in `GridView` using `C#`?

`ASP.NET` code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl="" Text="<%#Eval("pdfname") %>" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use eval:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("YourUrl") %>' Text='<%#Eval("pdfname") %>' runat="server"/>
```

In case your Url is in DataBound item property called "YourUrl"

If you need to construct it dynamically you can use method:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%# CreatePageUrl(Container.DataItem)%>' Text='<%#Eval("pdfname") %>' runat="server"/>
```

Define CreatePageUrl method in your code behind.

Comment: HyperLink2.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("Pdfhandler.ashx?empid=" + TextBox8.Text);      I need to pass this url. how should i write the code behind it in c#?

Comment: like this?    <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("Pdfhandler.ashx?empid=" + TextBox8.Text)%>' Text="<%#Eval("pdfname") %>" runat="server"/>

Comment: @user3168680 Do you need to set NavigateUrl property in aspx markup or cs code-behind?  Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("Pdfhandler.ashx?empid=" + TextBox8.Text)%>' Text='<%#Eval("pdfname") %>' runat="server"/>  this compiles just fine.

Comment: But grid is not displayed.

Comment: @user3168680 you are getting `server tag not well formatted` because it is not! The problem is here... `Text="<%#Eval("pdfname") %>"`. Change this to `Text='<%#Eval("pdfname") %>'`. Its `"` vs `'`!

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi check my last comment, it contains ' instead of "

Comment: Yes, @realnero I saw it. I was just trying to give more details to the OP. I see now that OP has got the point. By the way, @user3168680 you would be good with the `Eval` option as suggested by @realnero.

Comment: @realnero, though it is there in your comment, it is not there in your answer. Edit if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnRowDataBound Event of grid view find the hyperlink control then bind the url which u want. Example.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink hl= (HyperLink)e.Row.findControl("HyperLink2");   
            hl.NavigateUrl = "Your Url";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code behind but still grid is not being displayed.

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documents">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Target="_blank" Visible="False" 
                            Text="PDF File"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: This C# code:   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink2");
        hl.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("Pdfhandler.ashx?empid=" + TextBox8.Text);
    }

Comment: Confirm that your datasource is returning data. If there is no data, then the gridview won't get generated.

Comment: AS per your code in comment HyperLink2 is not visible ( Visible="False"). Please check your code

Comment: @user3168680 that is because u have not binding any thing to grid view. To resolve this put data in text property of hyperlink which coming from database. e.g. Text='<%# Bind("pdfname") %>'

Comment: Make sure there is data in your datasource.

Comment: Yes its there. Should I make any connection in design window?